# Passing variables to other programs

Tags: bash

In bash shell, I have a variable which prints a set of names. Now I would like to append an extension to it. I have sequence files with following names:

```
Meoh_R1.fastq
Meoh_R2.fastq
R3G_R1.fastq
R3G_R2.fastq
```

I have stored common names (Meoh and R3G in a variable). In bash I run following script without any problems:

```
# Stores common names in variable `i` (meoh and r3g) 
for i in $(ls ./raw_reads | grep ^[^d]| rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq)
do
    # Make direcotry for fastqc
    mkdir -p ${i%}_fastqc
    # Run fastqc
    fastqc -o ./${i%}_fastqc -f fastq ./rnaseq/${i%}_R1.fastq ./rnaseq/${i%}_R2.fastq
done
```

Now I run the following code which is not working:

```
filelist=$(ls ./raw_reads | grep ^[^d]| rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq)
mkdir -p ${i%}_fastqc
fastqc -o ./${filelist%}_fastqc -f fastq ./rnaseq/${filelist%}_R1.fastq ./rnaseq/${filelist%}_R2.fastq
```

Above code doesn't create individual folders like the working code provided above.

Comment: Why do you write `${i%}` instead of just `${i}`? The `%` modifier doesn't do anything if you don't put anything after it.

Comment: You can't put the whole file list variable in a single command line like that. It won't automatically split it up and repeat the command for each element. You need to use a loop like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get by without a loop:

```
filelist=$(ls ./raw_reads | grep ^[^d]| rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq)
echo "$filelist" | sed 's/.*/&_fastqc/' | xargs mkdir -p
echo "$filelist" | xargs -I{} fastqc -o ./{}_fastqc -f fastq ./rnaseq/{}_R1.fastq ./rnaseq/{}_R2.fastq
```

This will have the same effect as the loop, though, running fastqc once on each input file.